# PHP delivered jQuery UI components don't work?

Tags: php, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Below are the codes for 2 accordions (jquery ui). The first is hardcoded with html, and the second one is delivered to the page, on Document ready, via jquery.

HTML: [This accordion works]:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3><a href="">one</a></h3>
    <div>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>

    <h3><a href="">two</a></h3>
    <div>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</div>
</div>
```

PHP: [This accordion does not work]

```
echo'
<div class="accordion">

    <h3><a href="">One</a></h3>
    <div>111111aaaaa</div>

    <h3><a href="">Two</a></h3>
    <div>222222aaaaa</div>

    <h3><a href="">Three</a></h3>
    <div>333333</div>  
</div>
';
```

How do I make the dynamically delivered accordion also work?

EDITED:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#drag').draggable();
    $('.accordion').accordion();

    $.post('scripts/test.php', {  },
        function(output){
            $("div#test_php").html( output );
        }
    );

});
```

On Document Ready == set up the accordion functionality, and then request the second accordion from php script, embedding it into the DOM.
All the php script does is echo the code for a second accordion.

Comment: We need to see the JavaScript code that initializes the accordions.  You would not be able to initialize the accordion until after the jQuery call which requests it from PHP has completed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reinitialize the accordian again if you're injecting it dynamically into the DOM.

```
$.post('scripts/test.php', {  },
        function(output){
            $("div#test_php").html( output );
            $('.accordion').accordion();
        }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, and how do I "reinitialize the accordion" after it has been dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: Check my edit, you can do that in the callback function after your content is loaded.